# English word for someone who delves in poisons?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Like in some tribal society. Someone in position, like a folk healer, but is an expert at poisons and poisoning.

Comment: In some cultures, poisons are considered part of the usual methods used by witches or sorcerors.

Answer (score 2):

#### apothecary

From a [historical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothecary#History) stand point,

> Apothecaries dispensed viles or poisons as well as medicines, and as is still the case, medicines could be either beneficial or harmful if inappropriately used.

If you've ever read Romeo and Juliet, you may recall that Romeo purchased his vial of poison from an *apothecary* illegally.

---

If you are looking for the modern definition:

> a druggist; a pharmacist.

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/apothecary)

Comment: (+1) I've learned something new to day.

Comment: Person who "delves" in poisons? Has any such person ever existed long enough to acquire a name. I suppose what was intended was "deal" rather than "delve."